# Value Error: Shapes (None,128,128) and (None, 4) are incompatible

Tags: cnn, categorical-data

I am trying to perform CNN on my dataset. I came across the below error

```
ValueError: Shapes (None, 128, 128) and (None, 4) are incompatible
```

The shape of my xTrain and yTrain is as follows

```
(8, 128, 128, 3)
(8, 128, 128)
```

This is my CNN model

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=1, padding='valid', activation='relu', input_shape=(128, 128, 3)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(48, kernel_size=1, padding='valid', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
#model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
```

Please note that my yTrain data consists of values from 0-3, therefore output layer mapped as 4 in the last layer.

I am compiling my model as:

```
# Run the model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer= 'rmsprop',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(xTrain, yTrain, epochs=2)
```

I have looked into one of the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61742556/valueerror-shapes-none-1-and-none-2-are-incompatible) and made the following changes

```
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer= 'adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(xtrain, ytrain, epochs=2)
```

This gave me below error

```
logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [8,4] and labels shape [131072]
```

Where am I going wrong? Please guide.

Comment: The shape of your `yTrain` array is wrong, you are providing an array of shape `(8, 128, 128)` whereas it should be the same size as the array your model is predicting (i.e. `(4,)`. Make sure that the `yTrain` variable contains the labels that your model should be predicting.

Comment: @Oxbowerce 8 denotes the number of images, how can I change it to ```(4,)```, where 4 denotes number of classes my image has?

Comment: You shouldn't directly change the shape of the array, but you need to make sure that the array contains the data that you want your model to predict. Since I assume you simply want to predict a label given an image simply provide an array with the image labels to the `fit` method.